# HTML5 secure websocket connection within webworker on Chrome 61

Tags: html, google-chrome, websocket, web-worker

I'm running code to make secure websocket connection from web worker. It works fine in Chrome 60 but not in Chrome 61. In other browsers (IE,Firefox and Safari) it works fine.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an issue in Chrome 61 and it is fixed in Version 63.0.3213.0 (Official Build) canary.

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=760708